# How to solve lambda() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, lambda, typeerror

I have the following code snippet but it is giving me the type error above. What I basically wanted to do is add two to every element and reduct it to a single sum, but it didnt work. How can we achieve this??

```
import functools
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
result = functools.reduce(lambda x:x+2, list1)
print(result)
```

**Update:**

It works when I do the following though:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
result = functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, list1)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduce()` requires a lambda function which takes 2 arguments.
The first argument is the collector.
But here, so that `+2` is applied also on the first argument, you have to give the initial value 0.

```
import functools
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
result = functools.reduce(lambda acc, el: acc + el + 2, list1, 0)
print(result) ## sum([3, 4, 5, 6]) = 18
```

You basically want to do a normal summing `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, lst)` => `sum(lst)`
and a `map(lambda x: x + 2, l)` which is expressed in a more pythonic way as a list comprehension:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sum([x + 2 for x in l])            # most pythonic!
## 18
sum(map(lambda x: x + 2, l))
## 18
```

or:

```
import functools
l = [1, 2, 3 ,4]
result = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [x + 2 for x in l])
result ## 18
```

or:

```
import functools
l = [1, 2, 3 ,4]
result = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda x: x + 2, l))
result ## 18
```

Comment: I have added a snippted above. Can you tell me why it is working and why my initial code doesnt work @Gwang

Comment: your initial code has only 1 argument in lambda. The main problem. Lambda in reduce needs always 2 arguments. the first argument is that collecting the result. Your second argument is just `sum()` - it doesn't add 2 to every element.

Answer (score 1):

The callable passed to the `reduce` function needs to take two arguments to aggregate the current result with the next item from the given iterable:

```
import functools

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
result = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y + 2, list1, 0)
print(result)
```

This outputs:

```
18
```